# How can I transform a UIView from being parallel to the ground to being perpendicular?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calayer

I want to transform a view from a plane that is parallel to the ground to a plane that is perpendicular to the ground.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: you want to transform a view from a plane that is parallel to the ground to a plane that is perpendicular to the ground?

Comment: @MattBall, I really didn't get why this is not a real question? obviously I had trouble explaining my self due to language limitation and the nature of this question, but otherwise I believe this is a legit question, I have tried many things before asking it, search on google (not easy to search this specific q...), try to play with the CATransform3DScale and more.. MattBall I don't understan, you helping me by clarify the problem but then closing the q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate a view in 3D, you need to modify the `transform` property of the view's layer.

It sounds like you want to rotate the view around the X axis.  And I guess you want perspective, where the edge closer to the viewer appears larger and the edge farther from the viewer appears smaller.

We'll write a helper function that makes the transform.  We start with the identity transform:

```
static CATransform3D transformWithAngle(CGFloat angle) {
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
```

Then set the `m34` component of the transform based on the distance from the viewer to the view:

```
    transform.m34 = -1.0f / 300.0f;
```

If you use a number larger than `300`, the perspective will be weaker.  If you use a number smaller than `300`, the perspective will be stronger.

Next, add the rotation:

```
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 1, 0, 0);
```

Then return the transform:

```
    return transform;
}
```

Let's say you want to apply this to a view named `self.riseView`.  You probably want the rotation to be around the bottom edge of the view, so set the layer's anchor point to the bottom edge:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect frame = self.riseView.frame;
    self.riseView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 1.0f);
    self.riseView.frame = frame;
```

and initialize the layer's transform with an angle of 0:

```
    self.riseView.layer.transform = transformWithAngle(0);
}
```

You can make the view “set” (rotate down to the ground plane) by rotating it to an angle of `-M_PI_2`:

```
- (IBAction)setButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [self animateRiseViewToAngle:-M_PI_2];
}
```

and you can make it “rise” (rotate up) by rotating it to an angle of zero:

```
- (IBAction)riseButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [self animateRiseViewToAngle:0];
}
```

Here's how we actually do the animation:

```
- (void)animateRiseViewToAngle:(CGFloat)angle {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        self.riseView.layer.transform = transformWithAngle(angle);
    }];
}
```